# Moving to chat is showing with html chars

Tags: bug, status-completed

I asked a [user to continue discussion in a chat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25223515/1317935) in a question.

The posted text by Stackoverflow is not showing up correctly in the comments:

```
Let us <a href="chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59102/… this discussion in chat</a>. –  The Shift Exchange 7 mins ago
```

Seems to have the message parsed through a html filter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've introduced this bug as part of working on a related feature - sorry about that.

I have a fix ready to go, and it will be deployed in the next build.

Sorry about that!

Comment: You said "Sorry about that" twice.

Comment: @MrLister - 'cause I'm really, really, really sorry